# Embedding SVG in CSS via use reference

Tags: css, svg, inline-svg

I'm trying to reuse an inline SVG via an auto generated element in CSS, but it's not working as expected.

This is the SVG:

```
<svg><use xlink:href="#arrow"/></svg>
```

And after base64 encoding it into this CSS:

```
#icon:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2Zz48dXNlIHhsaW5rOmhyZWY9IiNhcnJvdyIvPjwvc3ZnPg==);
}
```

It fails to display the SVG

Here's a [more complete codepen](http://codepen.io/kowdermeister/pen/rOYEjO).

Comment: Don't data-URL have to be off-page?

Comment: If you open up the image in the browser you get the following result: error on line 1 at column 30: Namespace prefix xlink for href on use is not defined

Comment: Yes, because it's a reference, it should break. The base64 ecoded string is the reference too.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson, I'll look for another solution then. Repost this as an answer if you'd like it to be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an SVG is used in an image context, be that via `<img>` or in this case via a CSS background-image it must be complete in a single document. References outside the document are not allowed.

So #arrow must point to an element with the id arrow in that base64 encoded SVG document.